# Running Python code contained in a string

Tags: python, pygame, exec, eval

I'm writing a game engine using pygame and box2d, and in the character builder, I want to be able to write the code that will be executed on keydown events.

My plan was to have a text editor in the character builder that let you write code similar to:

```
if key == K_a:
    ## Move left
    pass
elif key == K_d:
    ## Move right
    pass
```

I will retrieve the contents of the text editor as a string, and I want the code to be run in a method in this method of Character:

```
def keydown(self, key):
    ## Run code from text editor
```

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the [`eval(string)`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) method to do this.

### Definition

`eval(code, globals=None, locals=None)`
The code is just standard Python code - this means that it still needs to be properly indented.

The globals can have a custom `__builtins__` defined, which could be useful for security purposes.

### Example

```
eval("print('Hello')")
```

Would print `hello` to the console. You can also specify local and global variables for the code to use:

```
eval("print('Hello, %s'%name)", {}, {'name':'person-b'})
```

### Security Concerns

Be careful, though. Any user input will be executed. Consider:

```
eval("import os;os.system('sudo rm -rf /')")
```

There are a number of ways around that. The easiest is to do something like:

```
eval("import os;...", {'os':None})
```

Which will throw an exception, rather than erasing your hard drive. While your program is desktop, this could be a problem if people redistributed scripts, which I imagine is intended.

### Strange Example

Here's an example of using `eval` rather strangely:

```
def hello() : print('Hello')
def world() : print('world')
CURRENT_MOOD = 'happy'

eval(get_code(), {'contrivedExample':__main__}, {'hi':hello}.update(locals()))
```

What this does on the eval line is:

1. Gives the current module another name (it becomes `contrivedExample` to the script). The consumer can call `contrivedExample.hello()` now.)
2. It defines `hi` as pointing to `hello`
3. It combined that dictionary with the list of current globals in the executing module.

### FAIL

It turns out (thanks commenters!) that you actually need to use the `exec` statement. Big oops. The revised examples are as follows:

---

### `exec` Definition

(This looks familiar!)
Exec is a statement:
`exec "code" [in scope]`
Where scope is a dictionary of both local and global variables. If this is not specified, it executes in the current scope.

The code is just standard Python code - this means that it still needs to be properly indented.

### `exec` Example

```
exec "print('hello')"
```

Would print `hello` to the console. You can also specify local and global variables for the code to use:

```
eval "print('hello, '+name)" in {'name':'person-b'}
```

### `exec` Security Concerns

Be careful, though. Any user input will be executed. Consider:

```
exec "import os;os.system('sudo rm -rf /')"
```

---

### Print Statement

As also noted by commenters, `print` is a statement in all versions of Python prior to 3.0. In 2.6, the behaviour can be changed by typing `from __future__ import print_statement`. Otherwise, use:

```
print "hello"
```

Instead of :

```
print("hello")
```

Comment: Note that this will only work in python3.  In python2.x "print" is a statement, not a function, so this gives a syntax error.  You'd need to use exec instead.

Comment: Yeah if he is using pygame he is using python2.x as I don't believe they have a python3 version.

Comment: The eval() function only supports evaluating Python expressions, not arbitrary statements. The exec statement must be used for statements.

Comment: I just tested this interactively, and yes, Greg is right (as expected!). I've modified my answer and kept the old stuff there for posterity. I've also included a not about the print statement.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, you can load the text into a string and use `exec "codestring"`.  If contained in a file already, using [execfile](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile) will avoid having to load it.

One performance note:  You should avoid execing the code multiple times, as parsing and compiling the python source is a slow process.  ie. don't have:

```
def keydown(self, key):
    exec user_code
```

You can improve this a little by compiling the source into a code object (with `compile()` and exec that, or better, by constructing a function that you keep around, and only build once.  Either require the user to write "def my_handler(args...)", or prepend it yourself, and do something like:

```
user_source = "def user_func(args):\n" + '\n'.join("    "+line for line in user_source.splitlines())

d={}
exec user_source in d
user_func = d['user_func']
```

Then later:

```
if key == K_a:
   user_func(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval)

Answer (score 0):

eval or exec. You should definitely read Python library reference before programming.